# query to fetch cpu core usage for windows?

Tags: windows, wmi, cpu-usage

I have to implement a code which populates the **cpu core usage per core**?

I was able to find information **per processor** but not for core.

Any **WMI query** or a **command** or an **API** which could fetch the usage of CPU cores.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor` or `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor` class? Namespace    `ROOT\CIMV2`

Comment: `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor` class

Comment: Did you get what you were finding?

Comment: Not exactly, will be looking it later, I voted your answer because it gave me somewhat direction, and still looking for precise solution...

Answer (score 1):

> `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor`

won't be useful because it is `uncooked` and you have to cook the counters to get something meaningful which requires lots of computation or you can use:

`Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor` which is already cooked.

Refer to : [WMI counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394569(v=vs.85).aspx)

> select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor where NOT name
>   = '_Total'

will give you counters per CPU.